# how to repeat alarm upto total time in android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, repeat

I want to call (GPSSetting)services up to Total Time By every Interval Time.

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(C2DMReceiver.this, GPSSetting.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                        C2DMReceiver.this, 0, intent1, 0);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 1, 5,
                        pendingIntent);
```

just here total time 1 and interval is 5 min then GPSService should call 12 times

Total time 1 hr and Interval time 5 in millsec
I want to be call GPSSetting (Service class) up to 1 hr ...every Interval

after 1 hr service should automaticaly stop;
Regards,
Girish

Comment: @pratik....please check now.    i want to be call GPSService upto 1 hr by every interval...just here total time 1 and interval is 5 min then GPSService should call 12 times

Comment: I didnot get cleared fully your question , can you explain in brief.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this way, I don't know it's correct way or not but try it

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent1 = new Intent(C2DMReceiver.this, GPSSetting.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(C2DMReceiver.this, 0, intent1, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, current_time, 5000,pendingIntent);
```

here you set the alarm with current time now this will update the alarm and notify every 5 min and you can call your service.

you need to keep this alarm intent instance and the current_time. compare this time with the after 1 hour time suppose you have current_time which was set into the alarm pass this value GPSSetting service and check with the time.

```
Calendar alarm_time = Calendar.getInstance();
alarm_time.setTime(you_alarm_time);

now add 1 hour in this and compare with the current time

alarm_time.add(Calender.HOUR,1); // this will add the 1 hour 

Calendar cur_time = Calendar.getInstance();

if(cur_time.after(alarm_time)){
   // cur_time is after alarm_time then cancel the alarm
}else{
   // do whatever you want
}
```

every time when you call this service it will define new object in you method so you just kept the alarm time when you set the alarm time or you can also kept that alarm time with pre-added 1 hour so you don't need to add 1 hour every time just compare that time with the current time.

Comment: sorry i have pass same object as alarm_time.setTime() pass your alarm time which you have set into the alarm.set() method